# Need Spring Framwork version as per Compatiblility Matrix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, spring-framework-beans, openjdk-17

Can anyone suggest a compatible Spring Framework version that can work for Spring Boot 2.x + OpenJDK 17 + IBM Webspehere 8.5.5.9

Comment: Ehrm, I would say no... I even doubt WebSphere 8.5 works with Java17...

Comment: Thanks for Response, So WebSphere 8.5.5.9 is compatible with any above version of JDK8
Where we can use SpringFramwork version (5.x or above) with Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: Spring 5 and Spring Boot 2 are perfectly able to work with JDK8. Your question was about JDK17, Spring and Spring Boot will support it **but** I doubt that WebSphere supports is.